# KickMe Command (python)

Tags: python, discord.py

I been making a discord bot that will kick you if you say some of his commands like !help idk what is the problem I tried everything it didn't work the bot is made with python code:

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True

TOKEN = 'no'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event

async def on_ready():

    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})')

@bot.event

async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == "!Help":

        if message.author.guild_permissions.kick_members:

            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, you've been kicked for using the command.")

            await message.author.kick(reason="Used the '!Help' command")

        else:

            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, you don't have permission to use that command.")

    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I was expecting when I say !Help it will kick me

Comment: Have you tried printing the message content before comparing to ensure it's being read at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some Intents here.

You are now required to add `message_content` as an Intent to read a message. You can also use `discord.Intents.all()` to directly import all the necessary Intents (*Make sure to enable them in the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) as well*)

**Your new code:**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True # Add this to read the content of the message

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

# Rest of the code
```

Refer to the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message_content#discord.Intents.message_content) for more information on this.